# wordpress wp-admin cannot access

Tags: php, wordpress, root

This is a new website, http://bioinformatics.hitsz.edu.cn/home/. There are no other new plugins and theme.
When i have installed the Wordpress, then login in, but i cannot access the wp-admin.
If i input the error user or password, then it remind me the error of user or password.

And if i input sub URL such as http://bioinformatics.hitsz.edu.cn/home/wp-admin/post-new.php into my browser, it is ok, so what's the problem, it puzzled me several days.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: sounds like .htaccess is not configured correctly

Comment: So how to configured correctly...thanks u!

Comment: This question is better suited for [wordpress.se]

Comment: Do you even look into ANY of your logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your .htaccess file.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Sounds like you removed one already or a permissions error.. Not really a stackoverflow question though.. More a superUser question IMO.